# Select Custom Column based on If Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

I have the following `Survey` Table

the columns are `Survey_Name, Question, Response, Weight, QuestionType`

What i want other than displaying the values in this table is to to display a custom column thats values depend on the other columns.

For example,

lets call the custom column `response_value`
I want this column to show the `weight` for the rows which have the `QuestionType` as 'Rating', and for the other question types, i want it to show `Response`, not the word, but the value of the field.

and yes, the `weight` and `response`columns are already in the table, but i want them to show in the custom column based on that condition.

so basically, it will be `Select * from Survey, Select (`[if statement here]`)`

help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select *, case when questiontype = 'Rating' 
               then cast(weight as signed)
               else response
          end as response_value
from survey
```

Comment: is it possible to set a data type for the response_value to be nvarchar? because I get an error that the column is int, and some response have text.

Comment: Add a `cast()` to the `int` value column.

Answer (score 1):

```
select *, if(questiontype = 'Rating',weight,response) as response_value from survey
```